# Is there a Python module that can contour data without gridding

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to contour a set of irregularly spaced data (2D contours in this case) without first gridding the data. The data are output from a model and I want the contours to fully honor the underlying data. Is there a Python module with this functionality, perhaps using Delaunay triangulation? Ideally I could export the contours as a shapefile, but could probably work with a matplotlib plot or similar. Also open to other open-source approaches if I can't figure it out in Python.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look @

Shapely https://github.com/sgillies/shapely
and

scipy Delaunay¶ http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using: matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour for direct contouring of the unstructured data (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tri#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf)

Comment: Shapely does not appear to support read/write of files, only spatial manipulation/analysis. I am looking for a way to write a gis format of file (i.e., shapefiles, dxf) from data that I am plotting in matplotlib (i.e., patches, tricontours, polygons, etc.).

Comment: I found an example python script that pointed me in the right direction for converting the contour sets from matplotlib to shapefiles and clipping them with another shapefile. It used osgeo and gslib. I found it here:http://bpgeo.googlecode.com/svn-history/r140/trunk/misc/numpy_to_shp.py